# How to use NDK-compiled JNI library in a normal non-Android Java application?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a JNI library that was made to be used by Android app with NDK.
I do not have sources, only compiled .so files for some archs.

I want to call functions from this library in a simple console Java application on a 64-bit x86 linux PC.

What I've done:

1. I took the library from x86_64 folder and loaded it in my Java program using `System.loadLibrary`
2. Tried to launch the program and got UnsatisfiedLinkError with details `liblog.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.
3. So I took liblog.so for x86_64 arch from official NDK and loaded it too, then got a same error with `libstdc++.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
4. Did the same thing for libstdc++.so library and got this `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so: invalid ELF header`.
5. Opened libc.so and it appeared to be just a text file... Replaced it with the proper libc.so file
6. Finally got UnsatisfiedLinkError for my library with `undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard` comment. Looks like my library is strongly tightened with Android things

What should I do to use this library in my normal program without anything Android-specific?

Comment: You can write your own liblog.so -- you don't need the Android one. In theory, you can replace the library name and the function names in the .so file (provided that you demangle/mangle them). But as to your situation at the moment, I would write a simple .so library using libc, make it work and then see what is the difference. "Invalid elf header" most likely means you have a lib for a different architecture. There used to be a Linux utility that prints out the ELF header to console. (In addition, on ARM, the v7 and pre-v7 libraries cannot be combined, maybe you have a similar issue.)

Comment: @18446744073709551615 Thank you! I've checked the type of libc.so and it appeared to be just a text file :D Opened it and found some paths to normal library inside. Copied it and... Look for step 6 in my question.

Comment: `__stack_chk_guard` -- looks like something related to `malloc()` implementation. Just replace the function that needs `__stack_chk_guard` with something that works on your architecture. Finally, you should be able to build libc for your architecture from the sources. (Well, your must have very special customers if you are seriously interested in this...)

Comment: hi @AnnaProsvetova, did u manage to do it? i have the same request from my client, and im trying to import it using python, but im stuck at step 4 of yours, where did you get `proper libc.so file`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just in few words - Android and desktop Linux binaries are **incompatible**, even if they are targeted to the same CPU architecture.

Comment: So does it mean I have absolutely no chance to use these Android x86_64 libraries on my Linux x86_64? And even if I take Android ARM libraries and try on Raspberry Pi (that's on ARM)?

Comment: @AndreyStartsev Occasionally it may work (if there is no android specific dependencies and you can load ELF files somehow). But surely there will surprises at runtime. Even if you've grabbed all usermode modules from android - kernels are a bit different and incompatible. Of course you can play with android binaries on desktop linux, but don't even think about using of such approach in production.