# Calling function from .so file created in android in linux C++ code

Tags: android, c++, c, java-native-interface

I have .so file which I take from apk. With command nm -D libnative-lib.so I took list of functions. I need to call function named `Java_com_example_nativelib_utils_Constants_getStringFromJNI` . I wrote the code below:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int init_library() {
    void* hdl = dlopen("./libnative-lib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if(hdl == 0)
        return 0;
    else return 1;
}

int main() {
    printf("%s\n", (init_library() ? "OK": "ERROR"));
}
```

and make file:

```
all: exe

exe:    main.c
        gcc main.c -fPIC -ldl -o main
```

but result of program is always "ERROR". I tried libnative-lib.so from x86 and armeabi-v7a architectures (others not present). How to load library and call function from it? C++ or C do not care.

Comment: remove -fPIC option and print error logs.  if (hdl==0) {
            fputs (dlerror(), stderr);
            exit(1); }

Comment: Thank you, I found where error was

Comment: you should check your LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use android .so files in non-android project. similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627742/how-to-use-ndk-compiled-jni-library-in-a-normal-non-android-java-application)